# GWT embedded ValueProxy stack overflow error

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

If I have a PersonProxy {String getName(); PersonProxy getParent();} and I try to load it from server through a RequestFactory provided Request object, it crashes with stack overflow error.
It tries to call hashCode() indefinitely.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a cycle in your PersonProxy relationships?  ValueProxies use their component properties' hashCode() and equals().  The ValueProxy type isn't really intended for use in complex graph structures, since they have no identity semantics to short-circuit graph traversals.

Comment: yes, as stated above, PersonProxy has a member of type PersonProxy, so I guess there is a cycle. Can I do anything to avoid/fix this?

Comment: Model the Person domain object with an EntityProxy.  If you can't retrofit the Person domain object with getId(), getVersion(), and findPerson() methods, you can define a Locator that will provide these services.  ValueProxies aren't intended to be used with non-trivial graph structures; they're really intended to say that a Car is painted some RgbColor, where you'd have a CarEntityProxy containing a reference to a RgbColorValueProxy.